# What is hot blocks in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am reading something online about some oracle issues where I am seeing hot blocks. But I couldn't found what are hot blocks. I understand that Oracle first read data from Disk to memory(buffer cache).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hot block is one that is accessed disproportionately often. One example would be an index block where the index is generated via a sequence; the database will need to write to the same block with the next value over and over again. This can make parallel operations difficult. To alleviate the situation you might use a reverse key so that the writes are spread across multiple blocks.

What strategy you use for your application will depend (that's always the answer) on your application and the 'demographics' of your data.